# CSS: match first word inside block

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have

```
<div class="dataTables_filter">
    <label>
    Search: <input type="text">
    </label>
</div>
```

And I want to hide the text "Search:" with css, how can I match the text "Search:" and apply display:none?

I tried matching the text as first-child of label but doesn't work instead it also hides the input

```
.dataTables_filter label:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

EDIT: please take my question literally: ie cannot change the HTML in any way just leverage css.

Comment: How about just using a span? `<label><span style="display:none;">Search:</span> <input type="text"></label>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pure CSS

You can use [the `:first-line` pseudo element](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-line), combined with a `font-size` of 0:

```
.dataTables_filter:first-line {
   font-size: 0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2MEWa/1).

Comment: This is not a answer, read question full after you give proper answer if possible. don't give this kind answer. first-line selector not find particular string from whole bunching word.

Comment: Setting `font-size:0` on the label also seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/2MEWa/2/ - without effecting the font-size of the input

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enveloping the term 'Search:' in a span tag? You could then probably give an id to the span tag and give display:none to the span tag.

Comment: I cannot change the html, that's why I'm asking how to do it with css

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is badly formatted. It should be as follows:

```
<label for="search">Search:</label> <input type="text" id="search" />
```

Your CSS would then be as follows:

```
.dataTables_filter [for=search] { display:none; } /* Don't reserve space for label */
```

OR

```
.dataTables_filter [for=search] { visibility:hidden; } /* reserve space for the label, but don't show its contents */
```

Comment: That's the html I get unfortunately, it's from datatables jquery plugin, https://datatables.net/

Answer (score -1):

Check this out This example.., [Example Link](http://redotheweb.com/2013/05/15/client-side-full-text-search-in-css.html)
This example uses CSS3 selectors (:not() and [attr*=]) and the rewriting of a style rule each time the search input is modified

create list with class name="searchable" and and few elements in list

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search" id="search">
<style id="search_style"></style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var searchStyle = document.getElementById('search_style');
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('input', function() {
if (!this.value) {
searchStyle.innerHTML = "";
return;
}

searchStyle.innerHTML = ".searchable:not([data-index*=\"" + this.value.toLowerCase() + "\"]) { display: none; }";

});
```

Comment: You shouldn't post link-only answers. This answer will become useless if the site you've linked to goes down.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.